# Bad MySQL performance for quite simple select

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, my.cnf

I've got a problem with perfomance of my mysql queries. I've got a very big table

```
create table query(
    id  Integer,
    session Integer,
    time    Integer,
    name    Integer,
    region  Integer);
```

Volume of data - 2 gb .I've made index on "name" - 7 gb.

My queries look like:

```
select count(id) from query where name=somevalue;
```

I wouldn't add any new data, and I used standard "my-huge.cnf". Still, I spend about 4-5 seconds per query, I'm going to do about 9-10*45000 queries. Which options should I change to increase speed, if my computer has 2gb memory.

Comment: More RAM is what you likely need.

Comment: Your data is 2GB but your index on a column from the table is 7GB?  Doesn't make sense...

Comment: Which engine (inno,myisam etc) are you using for the table? How many parallel queries you have in the same time?

Comment: invest in more ram or a SSD, also how is your index more than 3 times larger than the whole data?

Answer (score 2):

A count(*) may run marginally faster.

```
select count(*) as rowcount from query where name=somevalue;
```

Also you may consider caching the counts in a separate table and querying from that.

Comment: Thanks very much, it really helped. But I'm planning make some more complicated queries in the future, so I would have to increase somehow buffers anyway. But you just saved me 3-4 days of processing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're never changing the data, then you should consider running the queries for all possible names (`SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM query`) once, then storing the value of `COUNT()` in a cache. For that purpose, you could create a table `cache` with `name` and `total` as columns, and populate it with the results of running `SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS total FROM query WHERE name = 'name'` for each name.

You will then simply `SELECT total FROM cache WHERE name = 'name'`, which will be very fast.

Comment: It would help, if the problem was to get information of counts several times. I want to increase speed at the first collecting information. As the way for that I want use bigger buffers.